# The area of a triangle with sides $7$ and $8$ is $14\sqrt{3}$

Tags: geometry

The area of a triangle is $14\sqrt{3}$ $cm^2$. The lengths of two sides of the triangle are $7$ $cm$ and $8$ $cm$. Determine the type of $ABC$ based on angles.

Let $a=7$ and $b=8$ and $\measuredangle C=\gamma$. Then the area of $ABC$ is given by $$S_{\triangle ABC}=\dfrac12ab.\sin\gamma\iff 14\sqrt{3}=\dfrac12.7.8.\sin\gamma\\\Rightarrow\sin\gamma=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Rightarrow \gamma=60^\circ\cup\gamma=120^\circ$$
When $\gamma=120^\circ$ the triangle is obtuse-angled. If $\gamma=60^\circ$, can the triangle be right-angled or obtuse? Also I am not sure if we can say that $a=7$ and $b=8$ WLOG... Can we? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any two sides of a triangle are adjacent to each other and can be named appropriately. Once you choose a value for $\gamma$ the whole triangle is determined (draw a diagram). You can use the cosine formula for the last side.

Comment: In one case you have already identified it would be obtuse  scalene triangle. In case where angle between $a$ and $b$ is $60^0$, it cannot be right angled triangle because that would mean $\angle B$ is $90^0$ but $8 \cos 60^0 \ne 7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you rightly evaluated, $\angle C = 120^0$ or $60^0$.

And yes, WLOG $ \ a = 7, b = 8$.

[image]

i) When $\angle C$ is $120^0$:

$c \gt b \gt a$. So $\triangle ABC$ is obtuse angled triangle and a scalene triangle.

ii) When $\angle C$ is $60^0$:

One way is to apply law of cosine,

$c^2 = 7^2 + 8^2 - 2 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot \cos60^0 = 57$

Comparing with $a^2 = 49$ and $b^2 = 64$, we know $b$ is the longest side and $\angle B$ is the largest angle but we also note that $b^2 \lt a^2 + c^2 \ (64 \lt 49 + 57)$.

So this is an acute angled triangle and obviously a scalene triangle. Why acute angled? Because for it to be right angled triangle, we must have $b^2 = a^2 + c^2$ and for it to be obtuse angled triangle we must have $b^2 \gt a^2 + c^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using coordinate geometry.

You can assume WLOG that you can take the line bissector as $y$ axis, giving this figure:

[image]

with

$$A(7\cos \gamma,7\sin \gamma) \ \ \text{and} \ \ B(-8\cos \gamma,8\sin \gamma)\tag{1}$$

and area $$\frac12 \det(\vec{CA},\vec{CB})=56 \cos \gamma \sin \gamma = \underbrace{28 \sin 2 \gamma}_{f(\gamma)}$$

It remains to consider the curve of $f$ which crosses line $y=14 \sqrt{3}$ twice... and only twice: indeed, the solutions are the solutions of

$$\sin 2\gamma=\frac12=\sin 30° \iff \gamma=30° \ or \ \gamma=60°$$

(taking into account the fact that $0<\gamma<90°$).

As distance

$$AB=\sqrt{(x_B-x_A)^2+(y_B-y_A)^2}=\sqrt{225 \cos^2 \gamma+\sin^2 gamma}=\sqrt{1+224 \cos^2 \gamma}$$

giving $AB=13$ for $\gamma=30°$ and $AB=\sqrt{57}\approx 7.54$ for $\gamma=60°.$

we will not have a right angle in any of the two cases because Pythagoras theorem isn't verified.

Answer (score 1):

Let the base side of $\triangle ABC$ be $|BC|=a=7$,
so we have two points $B,C$ fixed.
The third point must be located on
the intersection of
a semicircle with the radius $|BA|=b=8$ centered at $C$
and a line parallel to $BC$ at a distance $h_a$:

[image]

The height $h_a$ can be easily found from the formula for the area $2S=h_a\,a$,
\begin{align}
h_a&=\frac{2S}a=\frac{2\cdot14\sqrt3}7=4\sqrt3
.
\end{align}

Clearly, there are two such points $A_1$, $A_2$,
one triangle is acute, another is obtuse,
and both are scalene.

Answer (score 0):

Wlog let $a=7,\ b=8$ and $S=14\sqrt3$.
It is more convenient to work with the squares,
$a^2=49,\ b^2=64,\ S^2=588$.

From Heron’s formula for the area in terms of square sides,

\begin{align}
16S^2&=4a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2
,
\end{align}
which leads directly to two valid lengths for the square of the third side,

\begin{align} 
c_1^2&=169,\quad c_1=13
,\\
c_2^2&=57,\quad c_2=\sqrt{57}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\cos\alpha_1&=\frac{-a^2+b^2+c_1^2}{2bc_1}
=\tfrac{23}{26}
,\\
\cos\beta_1&=\frac{a^2-b^2+c_1^2}{2ac_1}
=
=\tfrac{11}{13}
,\\
\cos\gamma_1&=\frac{a^2+b^2-c_1^2}{2ab}
=-\tfrac12
,
\end{align}
so, since all the side lengths are different and
$\cos\gamma<0$ in this case we have an obtuse scalene triangle,
but for the second option we have

\begin{align}
\cos\alpha_2&=\frac{-a^2+b^2+c_2^2}{2bc_2}
=\tfrac3{38}\sqrt{57}
,\\
\cos\beta_2&=\frac{a^2-b^2+c_2^2}{2ac_2}
=\tfrac1{19}\sqrt{57}
,\\
\cos\gamma_2&=\frac{a^2+b^2-c_2^2}{2ab}
=\tfrac12
,
\end{align}

that is, all the side lengths are still different but
the cosines of all three angles are positive,
hence in this case we have an acute scalene triangle.